# How to convert '(Data?, URLResponse, Error?) to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I don't understand why Im getting a error with `{` in this line. let task = URLSession

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse, error: Error?) in   //ERROR: Cannot convert value of type '(Data?, URLResponse, Error?) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

        self.removeActivityIndicator(activitiyIndicator: myActivityIndicator)

        if error != nil {
            self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Could not successfully perform this request")
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please **read** the error carefully, it says that the second closure parameter (`URLResponse`) must be optional (`URLResponse?`)

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
```

However to annotate the parameter types is not necessary

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
```

The compiler will complain if you treat the (optional) types wrongly.

And don't use `NS..` collection types in Swift. Use native types.